# Javascript unflatten array/change datastructure

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, data-structures

So heres the problem and heres the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6zqco0mj/

```
const start = [{'a':'b'}, {'b':'c'}, {'c':'d'}, {'d':'e'}]
end = 
{a:
  {b:
    {c:
      {
       d: {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have some code but not sure how would I dig deeper into an object

```
const start = [{'b':'c'}, {'a':'b'}, {'c':'d'}, {'d':'e'}];
const end = {};

function convert(key) {
  const obj = getObj(key);

  if(obj) {
    const temp = {};
    temp[obj[key]] = convert(obj[key]);
    //findKey(obj[key]);
    end[key] = temp;
  }
}

function getObj(key) {
  const foo = start.find((el, i) => { if(el[key]) { return el[key] } });
  return foo;
}

function findKey(k) {
// what goes here?  
}
convert('a');
console.log(end);
```

Comment: and what actually needs to be done? or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: is the data sorted?

Comment: Do you want to keep the original array un-altered? Can we use and mutate the original objects?

Comment: Also where did `e` go?

Comment: And what should happen if the data also happens to include `{'e': 'a'}`?

Comment: ... and how to handle cases where there are multiple branches and/or multiple roots?

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys

@MuhammadOmerAslam, just trying to kind of unflatten the array

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir, I do have a starting point for the array so wouldnt matter if the data is sorted would it? I can change the original array as well... also for my use case there arent multiple branches

Comment: @ScottSauyet, in my use case it wouldnt be cyclical but in case of {'e': 'a'} it should stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you went in the other way around for your aproach of recursivity; i gave it a try and this is what i got so far

```
const start = [{'b':'c'}, {'a':'b'}, {'c':'d'}, {'d':'e'}];


function convert(key, object) {
   const obj = getObj(key);

 if(obj) {
   object[obj[key]] = {};
   convert(obj[key], object[obj[key]]);
 }
}

 function getObj(key) {
  const foo = start.find((el, i) => { if(el[key]) { return el[key] }});
  return foo;
}

const end = { a: {}};

convert('a', end.a);
 console.log(end);
```

Comment: Almost there... am unable to see why a isnt being added at the root of the end object :?

Comment: I edited the answer, the convert first call had to be changed to get the entry point

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object structure for collecting the data and build the tree.

This solutiotion works with unsorted data.

For getting the root properties, all keys and values are collected and only the subset is taken.

```js
var data = [{ d: 'e' }, { b: 'c' }, { c: 'd' }, { a: 'b' }, { b : 'z' }],
    tree = function (data) {
        var keys = new Set,
            values = new Set,
            r = Object.create(null);

        data.forEach(function (o) {
            var [key, value] = Object.entries(o)[0];
            keys.add(key);
            values.add(value);
            r[value] = r[value] || {};
            r[key] = r[key] || {};
            r[key][value] = r[key][value] || r[value];
        });

        values.forEach(v => keys.delete(v));
        return Object.assign(...Array.from(keys, k => ({ [k]: r[k] })));
    }(data);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I know the question is short on details, but is there any reason to assume that that this is single-rooted?  I was going down a similar path, but realized that if you throw `{x: 'b'}` into the input, it vanishes in the output.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, it would work now, but it takes the same reference to `b`.